# How can I create two different tab layouts platform specific (iOS tabbar botttom, Android tabbar top) in Ionic 2?

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to code on Ionic code but I notice that both iOS and Android with the tabs template put the tabbar at the bottom and I want to do it platform specific. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i think by default you will get it you no need to some thing externally

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide by ionic http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/

I think you'll find your answer there. Using the `md` and `ios` styles.

Following this link and the link in that guide:

```
ionicBootstrap(AppRoot, customProviders, {
  tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
  platforms: {
  md: {
    tabsPlacement: 'top',
  }
  ios:{
    tabsPlacement: 'bottom',
  }
});
```